# How can I select/click an element with a for="" attribute? [protractor]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm writing a protractor test. I want to click on an element with the text "Click Me",  how can I grab such an element with the following attribute:

```
//view
 <label class = "tile-label ng-binding" for="public1">
      Click Me
 </label>
```

Comment: You might want to reconsider how you're going about this.  If you're building a customer-facing  web-application and you're using "label"s and "for" attributes, then clearly you care about accessibility.  Doing some JavaScript to create a click event on a label is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding it [by.cssContainingText](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText)

**Edit:** The other answers assume the OP has control of the underlining code, which to me doesn't seem like the case. Obviously we would all love appropriate identifiers/best practices when trying to write tests but sometimes that just isn't the case. Best of luck!

Comment: Setup like the following?

Comment: `var clickMe = element(by.cssContainingText('.title-label', 'Click Me'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<label class = "tile-label ng-binding" for="public1">
     <input type="checkbox" id="public1"/>Click me</label>
```

Comment: The question is about locating the element inside a Protractor end-to-end test.

Answer (score 0):

To get the element by the text *reliably*, you can use the xpath location technique:

```
element(by.xpath("//label[normalize-space(.) = 'Click Me']")).click();
```

where [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) helps to trim the extra spaces and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
element(by.css('label[for="public1"]')).click();
```